# How to create nginx ingress controller for private AKS cluster

Tags: azure-aks, nginx-ingress

Am looking for any options on creating creating nginx ingress controller for private AKS cluster.
The microsoft documents only mentions about the public cluster.

Thanks
Raam

Answer (score 2):

A private AKS cluster is a cluster where the API endpoint is private (so the masters), but not the node pools with the actual workloads (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters).

To install an NGINX ingress just follow the normal installation flow and it will work - but of course you will have to connect to your cluster using a valid method like a VM in the same VNET, for example.

If what you want to do is to create an ingress that is **accessible only from inside your VNET**, what you need is an ingress associated with an internal load balancer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-internal-ip).

**For NGINX with HELM**

Create a file called internal-ingress.yaml with this content:

```
controller:
  service:
    loadBalancerIP: YOUR_PRIVATE_IP_HERE
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

Then install NGINX with HELM applying the file in question:

```
# Create a namespace for your ingress resources
kubectl create namespace ingress-basic

# Add the ingress-nginx repository
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx

# Use Helm to deploy an NGINX ingress controller
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace ingress-basic \
    -f internal-ingress.yaml \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the above steps using az aks command and end up with the below error.az aks command invoke -g aks-rg -n aks-demo-private-westus -c "helm install nginx-ingress-1 ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace private-ingress-basic -f internal-ingress.yaml --set controller.replicaCount=2 --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux"
Error: mkdir /.cache: permission denied

Comment: I think for this error you would need to check the comment you got in the other answer. My suggestion would be to do it from a VM in the network space of your cluster - it will be simpler. Also, consider the AKS Run Command is in preview and it could be it will not work.

Answer (score -1):

To create an Nginx Ingress Controller for a private Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster, you can follow these steps:

1. Set up the Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) private cluster:

   - Create a virtual network (VNet) with a subnet that has the "Private Endpoint" option enabled.
   - Create an AKS cluster using the private subnet and VNet.
   - Configure the necessary network peering or VPN gateway connections for connectivity.
2. Deploy the Nginx Ingress Controller:

   - Connect to your AKS cluster using the Azure CLI or Azure Portal.
   - Deploy the Nginx Ingress Controller using a Kubernetes manifest or Helm chart.

   **Using Kubernetes Manifest:**

   ```yaml
   # Create a file named nginx-ingress.yaml and paste the following content

   apiVersion: apps/v1
   kind: Deployment
   metadata:
     name: nginx-ingress-controller
     namespace: ingress-nginx
     labels:
       app: nginx-ingress
   spec:
     replicas: 1
     selector:
       matchLabels:
         app: nginx-ingress
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           app: nginx-ingress
       spec:
         containers:
           - name: nginx-ingress-controller
             image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.34.1
             args:
               - /nginx-ingress-controller
               - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-controller
               - --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
             env:
               - name: POD_NAME
                 valueFrom:
                   fieldRef:
                     fieldPath: metadata.name
               - name: POD_NAMESPACE
                 valueFrom:
                   fieldRef:
                     fieldPath: metadata.namespace
             ports:
               - name: http
                 containerPort: 80
               - name: https
                 containerPort: 443
   ---
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: nginx-ingress-controller
     namespace: ingress-nginx
     labels:
       app: nginx-ingress
   spec:
     type: LoadBalancer
     ports:
       - name: http
         port: 80
         targetPort: 80
       - name: https
         port: 443
         targetPort: 443
     selector:
       app: nginx-ingress
   ```

   Save the file and apply the manifest to your cluster:

   ```bash
   kubectl apply -f nginx-ingress.yaml
   ```

   **Using Helm:**

   ```bash
   helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
   helm repo update
   helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx
   ```

   This will deploy the Nginx Ingress Controller to the `ingress-nginx` namespace.
3. Verify the deployment:

   - Check the deployment and services to ensure the Nginx Ingress Controller is running:

   ```bash
   kubectl get deployment -n ingress-nginx
   kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
   ```

   - Make sure the Nginx Ingress Controller's external IP or DNS is accessible within your private network.
4. Configure Ingress resources:

   - Create or update Ingress resources in your AKS cluster to define the routing rules for your services. For example:

   ```yaml
   # Create a file named example-ingress.yaml and define your Ingress rules

   apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
   kind: Ingress
   metadata:
     name: example
   ingress
   spec:
     rules:
       - host: example.com
         http:
           paths:
             - pathType: Prefix
               path: /
               backend:
                 service:
                   name: example-service
                   port:
                     number: 80
   ```

   Apply the Ingress resource:

   ```bash
   kubectl apply -f example-ingress.yaml
   ```

   This example Ingress resource routes requests for `example.com` to the `example-service` running on port 80.
5. Configure DNS:

   - Add DNS records or modify existing ones to point to the Nginx Ingress Controller's external IP or DNS name.

   Note: If your private AKS cluster has an internal DNS resolution mechanism, configure DNS accordingly.

That's it! You have now created an Nginx Ingress Controller for your private AKS cluster and configured Ingress routing. Incoming requests to the specified domain will be directed to the corresponding services within your cluster.